# Spring MVC и Объект с Set

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

У меня есть 2 класса замапеных в гибернейте: 
Класс реализующий сущность счёта, любой счёт имеет id, цену, владельца, а главное - тип счёта, **которых может быть несколько**. Те у одного счёта может быть несколько типов.

```
 Account.class
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "dp_account",
            uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"id"})})
        public class Account {

            @Id
            @Column(name="id", nullable = false, unique = true, length = 11)
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
            private long id;

            @Column(name = "price", nullable = false)
            private int price;

            @Column(name = "customer_id", nullable = false, unique = true, length = 11)
            private long customerId;

            @Column(name = "customer", length = 100, nullable = false, unique = true)
            private String customer;

            @Column(name = "comment", length = 1000)
            private String comment;

            @Column(name = "date", columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP")
            @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
            private Date date;

            @Column(name = "is_deleted", nullable = false)
            private boolean deleted = false;

            @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = AccountType.class, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
            @JoinTable(name = "account_accountType",
                    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "account_id") },
                    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "type_id") })
            private Set<AccountType> accountTypes;
        // дальше конструкторы и геттеры/сеттеры
        }
```

Сущность типа счёта, которая имеет название, описание, id и самое главное - имя владельца.

```
    AccountType.class
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "account_type")
    public class AccountType {
        private static final Long serialVersionUID = -4727727495060874301L;

        @Id
        @Column(name = "id")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private long id;

        @Column(name = "name", length = 25, nullable = false, unique = true)
        private String name;

        @Column(name = "description", length = 255)
        private String description;

        @Column(name = "user_login", length = 45, nullable = false, unique = true)
        private String login;
   //дальше геттеры/сеттеры и конструкторы
}
```

Вопрос в следующем: У меня есть страница, на которой я заполняю форму для создания счёта (`Account.class`), делаю `multiple select`, для заполнения типов счетов (`AccountType.class`). В самом классе Account есть поле `Set<AccountType> accountTypes`, в котором у каждого счёта содержится список его типов. (Именно этот список я и пытаюсь заполнить, а затем передать Account.class в MVC контроллер). Но в контроллер я даже не попадаю, получаю 400 ошибку. После многочисленных тестов я понял, что Spring MVC не забиндил мой список, хотелось бы узнать, как это сделать?

Код контроллера:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/account/addAccount", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public void addAccount(@ModelAttribute("accountAttribute") Account account) {
            System.out.println("Account on the top");
            System.out.println(account);
            ServiceFactory.getInstance().getAccountService().addAccount(account);
        }

@RequestMapping(value = "/welcome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView welcomePage() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorityList = (List<GrantedAuthority>) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities();
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String login = authentication.getName();
        if (grantedAuthorityList.contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"))) {
            model.setViewName("admin");
        } else {
            List<AccountType> accountTypes = ServiceFactory.getInstance().getAccountService().getAllAccountTypeByLogin(login);
            model.addObject("accountTypes", accountTypes);
            model.setViewName("user");
        }
        return model;
    }
```

Код JSP

```
<div style="margin-top: 40px">
            <form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/account/addAccount" method="post" modelAttribute="accountAttribute">

                <label>
                    Сумма: <input type="number" name="price">
                </label>
                <br> <br>

                <label>
                    Категория:
                    <select multiple name="accountTypes">
                        <c:forEach items="${accountTypes}" var="accountType">
                        <option value="${accountType.name}">${accountType.name}</option>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </select>
                </label>
                <br><br>

                <label>Комментарий:
                    <br> <br>
                    <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea>
                </label>
                <br><br>

                <input type="submit" value="Внести">

            </form:form>
        </div>
```

Скриншот: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я смог решить эту проблему, я стал передавать отдельно Set и отдельно сам объект Account. Проблема была в том, что я передавал из jsp Account и хотел сразу же получить Set, а это было невозможно из-за того выбирал я только **название** типа счёта, а не сам счёт. Вот решение проблемы:

JSP:

```
<form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/account/addAccount" method="post" modelAttribute="accountAttribute">

                <label>
                    Сумма: <input type="number" name="price">
                </label>
                <br> <br>

                <select multiple name="accountTypeNameSet" size="4s">
                    <c:forEach items="${accountTypes}" var="accountType">
                        <option >${accountType}</option>
                    </c:forEach>
                </select>

                <label>Комментарий:
                    <br> <br>
                    <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea>
                </label>
                <br><br>

                <input type="submit" value="Внести">

            </form:form>
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/account/addAccount", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void addAccount(@ModelAttribute("accountAttribute") Account account, @RequestParam(value="accountTypeNameSet") Set<String> accountTypeNameSet) {
    // implementation here
// accountTypeNameSet - это наш список названий типов счетов, который выбрал пользователей. На основе этих названий мы можем вытащить нужные счета из бд.
```

Answer (score 1):

разве обычный инпут работает как путь к полю объекта? 
вы передаете пустую форму и получаете ошибку, которая, если мне не изменяет память говорит о том, что передаваемый тип не правильный.
Попробуйте сделать так:

```
<div style="margin-top: 40px">
        <form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/account/addAccount" method="post" commandName="accountAttribute">

            <label>
                Сумма: <form:input type="number" path="price">
            </label>
            <br> <br>

            <label>
                Категория:
                <form:select path="..." multiple name="accountTypes">
                    <c:forEach items="${accountTypes}" var="accountType">
                    <form:option value="${accountType.name}">${accountType.name}</form:option>
                    </c:forEach>
                </form:select>
            </label>
            <br><br>

            <label>Комментарий:
                <br> <br>
                <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea>
            </label>
            <br><br>

            <input type="submit" value="Внести">

        </form:form>
    </div>
```

Я изменил `modelAttribute` но `commandName` хотя считается что это альтернативные атрибуты, но у меня однажды была с этим проблема и замена ее решила. 
Форму вы создали через отдельный класс или методом с аннотацией `ModelAttribute(name="accountAttribute")` в контроллере? 
Если вы создаете методом, у вас не получится передать поле `accountType` как объект, по этому нужно создать отдельный класс форму или создать еще одно поле(которое не должно сериализоваться, хотя я полагаю гибернейт знает что ему делать, для безопасности можете добавить к нему модификатор `volatile`), которое будет содержать передаваемое `id` именно этого типа и дописать его в `path=".."`, которое я оставил пустым. 
И еще, не используйте примитивные типы в моделях.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ваш исчерпывающий ответ. Я написал в вопросе как делал в контролере, public void addAccount(@ModelAttribute("accountAttribute") Account account). Создать отдельный класс форму (не могли бы пояснить, как именно), но больше интересен второй вариант решения. "которое будет содержать передаваемое id именно этого типа и дописать его в path=".." " Не очень понял идею с id. В классе Account добавить поле содержащие id, в котором будет храниться id  AccountType? Если вы могли бы показать наглядно, это было бы замечательно.

Comment: @GermanSevastyanov добавьте меня в skype: dmytro_khodan.

Comment: Отлично, спасибо

Comment: Правда дома буду только через несколько часов.

Comment: @GermanSevostyanov хорошо. я вечером возможно буду занят, но просто маякните и посмотрим. если что утром созвонимся.

Comment: Хорошо, утром буду на связи :)

Comment: Я решил проблему и оформил ответ в виде решения, если интересно - посмотрите :)