# Spring mvc отправка массива объектов в servlet

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Допустим у меня есть две сущности: статьи и категории с отношением ManyToMany:

```
public class Category {

  public String name;   

  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "categories")
    public List<News> news;
}



 public class News implements Serializable{

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "news_categories", schema = "public",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "news_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    public List<Category> categories;
}
```

И у меня есть простая jsp страничка для создания новых статей. На этой страничке я подгружаю сначала все теги и отображаю через select для выбора в форме. Но я понять не могу: как правильно передавать массив объектов, которые находятся внутри базового объекта?

Формирую я этот список в виде select таким образом:

```
<form:select multiple="true" path="categories" items="${categories}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="id" />
```

Метод, который принимает запрос от формы:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/news/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView add(@ModelAttribute("newsAttribute")News news){

        newsService.add(news);

        return new ModelAndView("addedpage");
    }
```

Когда я пытаюсь отправить форму сейчас, то мне в ответ приходит 400 ошибка с текстом:

> The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect

Содержание формы, когда я отправляю на сервер:

[image: описание]

Так же я не могу понять откуда берется третий параметр "_categories". Что мне следует поменять чтобы я мог присваивать массив категорий статье, когда её создаю?

Comment: Наткнулся на тему [ссылка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/501707/spring-mvc-%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D1%81-set?rq=1) и решил сделать примерно так же: добавил еще один параметр к методу List<Long> tags. С jsp страницы получается я передаю просто массив идентификаторов, но в контроллере приходится подгружать по этим идентификаторам записи тегов из базы, т.к. если передавать только id, то затираются остальные поля. Мне этот способ кажется неудобным поэтому жду еще варианты как это правильно можно сделать.

Comment: Если интересен код, то [здесь](https://github.com/Lokimora/JavaSpringNews) можно посмотреть. Надеюсь я не добавил лишние файлы в .gitignore т.к. плохо еще в архитектуре фрейморка разбираюсь.